# Importing airflow variables in a json file using the command line

Tags: json, command-line-interface, airflow

I have file called `properties.json` which looks like

```
{
  "FOO": {
    "var1": "apple",
    "settings": {
      "more_settings": {
        "var2": "pear",
        "var3": 123
      }
    }
  },
  "BAR": "FOO"
}
```

and I'm trying to import into Airflow via the command line interface like so

```
gcloud composer environments run <composer-name> \
        --location <location> --project <project> variables -- \
        --import /path/to/properties.json
```

in order to get the following variables into Airflow:

`FOO: { "var1": "apple", "settings": { "more_settings": { "var2": "pear", "var3": 123 } } }`

`BAR: FOO`

However, when I run the gcloud command, I get the error `Missing variables file.` When I import `properties.json` in Airflow's UI, it is imported without issues. What am I doing wrong by using the CLI?

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#variables

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103465/how-to-set-get-airflow-variables-which-are-in-json-format-from-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this:

```
airflow variables import properties.json
```

According to: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#import_repeat2

Answer (score 2):

For older versions 1.10.x of Airflow, using CLI, the syntax is:

```
airflow variables -i <file.json>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue with running Airflow on Docker. When running this command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo docker-compose run airflow-worker airflow variables import variable.json
```

I get this reponse:

```
Missing variables file.
ERROR: 1
```

I realized (finally) that I am getting this response because I'm running Airflow ***on Docker***.
My command above is giving a job to an Airflow worker to import a JSON file - but this worker has no access outside the container and so it doesn't 'see' the file I'm referring to at all.

The only solution I have now is simply to pass all values I need to use via the command itself. For example, this command works with no problems:

```
sudo docker-compose run airflow-worker airflow variables set my_var {\"test_key\":\"test_val\"}
```

However, I also just learned it is possible to set variables within the DAG file itself ([more info here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html)) and I might do that instead.