# Importing airflow variables in a json file using gitlab ci/cd

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, airflow, cicd, google-cloud-composer

How to import variables using gitlab ci/cd yml file.
I  have found [Importing airflow variables in a json file using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068819/importing-airflow-variables-in-a-json-file-using-the-command-line) but not helping out

Answer (score 0):

You can import a `Json` file as `Airflow` variables.

`variables.json` file :

```json
{
  "feature": {
    "param1": "param1",
    "param2": "param2",
    ...
  }
}
```

For example, this file can be put in the following structure :

```
my-project
   config
       dags
         variables
            dev
               variables.json
            prd
               variables.json
```

You can then create a `Shell` script to deploy these variables and file to `Cloud Composer`, `deploy_dags_config.sh` file :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u

export FEATURE_NAME=my_feature
export ENV=dev
export COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT=my-composer-env
export ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION=europe-west1
export GCP_PROJECT_ID=my-gcp-project

echo "### Deploying the data config variables of module ${FEATURE_NAME} to composer"

# deploy variables
gcloud composer environments storage data import \
  --source config/dags/variables/${ENV}/variables.json \
  --destination "${FEATURE_NAME}"/config \
  --environment ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT} \
  --location ${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION} \
  --project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}

gcloud beta composer environments run ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT} \
  --project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
  --location ${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION} \
  variables import \
  -- /home/airflow/gcs/data/"${FEATURE_NAME}"/config/variables.json

echo "Variables of ${FEATURE_NAME} are well imported in environment ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT} for project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID}"
```

This Shell script is the used in `Gitlab CI` yaml file :

```yaml
deploy_conf:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:416.0.0
  script:
    - . ./authentication.sh
    - . ./deploy_dags_config.sh
```

Your Gitlab have to be authenticated to `GCP`.

In the `Airflow` DAG code, the variables can be then retrieved in a `Dict` as follow :

```py
from typing import Dict
from airflow.models import Variable

variables:Dict = Variable.get("feature", deserialize_json=True)
```

Because the root node of `variables.json` file and object is `feature` (this name should be unique) :

```json
{
  "feature": {
    "param1": "param1",
    "param2": "param2",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @RakeshSabbani I have you solved your issue ?